# Why does using a constant value in the WHERE part of my mysql query work and using a variable does not when i sort in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'll get right to it.

I am trying to sort a user list by either desc or asc in Codeigniter.

My **Controller** looks like this -

```
/**
 * List issues by specified user
 */
public function ByUser($sort_by = 'issue_date', $sort_order = 'desc')
{
    /**
     * Store _POST value from dropdown in variable - $user_type.
     * Pass that value to model to get issues only "by that user"
     */
    $user_type = $this->input->post('issues-by-user');

    $data['records'] =  $this->report_model->issues_by_user($sort_by,$sort_order, $user_type);

    $data['main_content'] = 'report';
    $data['title'] = 'MarksMate Report';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

In my **Model**, i have an inner join that joins two tables and fetches issues by specific user.

My **Model** method looks like this -

```
public function issues_by_user($sort_by, $sort_order, $user_type)
{
    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'asc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    $sort_columns = array('id', 'issue_date');
    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'issue_date';

    $query = $this->db->select('tblissue.id, student_id, issue_date, issue_title, issue_description, issue_screenshot, first_name, last_name, email_id, role')
                    ->from('tblissue')
                    ->join('tblstudentprofile', 'tblissue.student_id=tblstudentprofile.id')
                    ->where('role', $user_type)
                    ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $records = $query->get()->result_array();

    return $records;
}
```

Query works fine. (Checked it using print_r)

But when i change the url to -  "http://localhost/anothertrack/report/ByUser/id/asc", all the records that were fetched go away. If i print_r, all i see is an empty array.

However, if i remove the variable `$user_type` from `->where('role', $user_type)`  and instead put a constant value like 0 or 1 or 2 (0,1,2,3 are my enum values set in database) then it works.

I have checked syntax for mysql query but its fine. I have also gone through Codeigniters URI class manual. I have no clue as to where in my code i may be wrong. Help me? Please?

Comment: what returns var_dump() of received GET parameters?

Comment: Clearly, the $user_type isn't being set correctly...

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo Thanks Sergio. This is what i get `array(0) { }`

Comment: @Devon Yes but i checked the syntax and there's nothing wrong there. It shouldn't be a problem because i am passing it as the 3rd parameter, should it?

Comment: @pistonracer, did you ever verify $user_type held the correct data before passing it as the 3rd parameter?  The answer below is what I was getting at. You didn't do very extensive debugging.

Comment: @Devon I have mentioned in my question that the query works fine. I was able to fetch records according to the enum value stored in `$user_type` variable.

Comment: @pistonracer if you don't understand what I, or the answer below, is saying then you to look into the difference between a post and a get request and have some other learning resource available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
$user_type = $this->input->post('issues-by-user');
```

When you go directly to `http://localhost/anothertrack/report/ByUser/id/asc`

There was no POST data. You may use Codeigniter segmentation method. E.g:

```
$user_type = $this->uri->segment(6);
```

Now, you can go with:

`http://localhost/anothertrack/report/ByUser/id/asc/issuebyuser`

Comment: Thank you. Doesn't work if i specify the segment like you said `$user_type = $this->uri->segment(6);` Works if i DON'T specify the segment. Why and How?

Comment: The `segment(6)` will grab `issuebyuser`...if you not specify then `$user_type` will be not set or null or empty ....

So you need to specify what the value of `issubyuser` need to be put on your url.

You may refer to this url for more details:
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is my another suggestion, you may use Codeigniter Session. I realized your workflow comment:

> /**
>            * Store _POST value from dropdown in variable - $user_type.
>            * Pass that value to model to get issues only "by that user"
>            */

```
public function ByUser($sort_by = 'issue_date', $sort_order = 'desc')
{
    /**
     * Store _POST value from dropdown in variable - $user_type.
     * Pass that value to model to get issues only "by that user"
     */

    $user_type = $this->input->post('issues-by-user');
    if($user_type)
    {
       $this->session->set_userdata('issues-by-user');
    }

    $data['records'] =  $this->report_model->issues_by_user($sort_by,$sort_order, $user_type);

    $data['main_content'] = 'report';
    $data['title'] = 'MarksMate Report';
    $this->load->view('includes/template', $data);
}
```

and in your model:

```
public function issues_by_user($sort_by, $sort_order, $user_type)
{
    $sort_order = ($sort_order == 'asc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
    $sort_columns = array('id', 'issue_date');
    $sort_by = (in_array($sort_by, $sort_columns)) ? $sort_by : 'issue_date';

    $query = $this->db->select('tblissue.id, student_id, issue_date, issue_title, issue_description, issue_screenshot, first_name, last_name, email_id, role')
                    ->from('tblissue')
                    ->join('tblstudentprofile', 'tblissue.student_id=tblstudentprofile.id')
                    ->where('role', $this->session->userdata('issues-by-user'))
                    ->order_by($sort_by, $sort_order);

    $records = $query->get()->result_array();

    return $records;
}
```

So you can use your current url to get issues **only by that user**:

```
http://localhost/anothertrack/report/ByUser/id/asc/
```